# Strange behavior in neo4j when I try to get all the nodes which relate with a master node

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to write a query which will give me all the nodes which are connected with a "master" node. Lets say that the node connect like this:

```
      A -> B
      B -> C
      C -> D
      C -> E
      B -> F
```

What I want initially is to write a query which will return to me all the node's names under the master node A. All the nodes are related with a "contain" relationship.

I wrote this query:

```
MATCH (n {gid:'58749'})-[:contains*]-(z) RETURN z as names
```

When I run this query in the neo4jServer I get a nice graph, which shows indeed all the nodes which are related. 
BUT when I check the "table" vizualisation of the date (not the graph) I get much more results. 
As you can see in the pictures in the first one on the button it says: displaying 8 nodes 9 relationships but in the second one (for the same think) it says: "returned 48 rows).
So, the question is: what the heck is going on??

[image]

[image]

**EDITED**

Changing the query to this:

```
      MATCH (n {gid:'58749'})-[:contains*]-(z) RETURN distinct(z) as names
```

solves partially the problem.
Nodes with the same name (id) will be aggregated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that what's returned in the graph is a representation of the total result set; this includes all sub-graphs/sub-paths that comprise the result set.  In the tabular representation, you're going to get all sub-paths, etc. the comprise the result set.

E.g. A->B->C->D is in the graph, but in the table, you're going to see, A->B, A->B->C, A->B->C->D, etc.  This is because of the Cypher statement you have which is looking for all nodes that have a "contains" relationship of ANY depth (also, the query looks for such relationships in either direction).

So, while you may only have 8 nodes and 9 relationships in total, the Cypher pattern you're matching is going to be a combination of those 8 nodes and 9 relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The question is how can I get using a cypher query (with php) all the nodes once?

Comment: If you want all nodes at once, simply do `match n return n;`  But this answer here addresses your original question.

Comment: I meant all the nodes which are related to the master node (node A). I want all these nodes just once.