# Use neo4jphp to get an array with all the nodes related to a master node

Tags: neo4j, neo4jphp

I use Neo4jPHP to write a snippet which will give me an array of all the nodes which are connected with a "master" node (A). The node connect like this:

```
  A -> B
  B -> C
  C -> D
  C -> E
  B -> F
```

This is the code I wrote using neo4jPHP:

```
$client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client();
$querystring="MATCH path=(n {gid:'58731'})-[:contains*]-(z) RETURN ([x in nodes(path) | x.id]) as names";
$query=new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client,$querystring); 
$result=$query->getResultSet();

foreach($result as $resultItem){
    $resultArray[] = $resultItem['n'];
}   
print_r($resultArray); // prints the array
```

The problem is that the $resultArray stores the nodes which relate to the master node repeatedly (like explained here: [Strange behavior in neo4j when I try to get all the nodes which relate with a master node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966939/strange-behavior-in-neo4j-when-i-try-to-get-all-the-nodes-which-relate-with-a-ma) )

My question is: Is there a way using neo4jPhp to get back an array which will contain all the nodes which are related to the "master" node only once?
Something like this:

```
 $distinctNodes = [B,C,D,E,F]
```

Thanks
D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should directly return the array:

```
MATCH (n {gid:'58731'})-[:contains*1..]->(z) RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT z.id) as names
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One issue I have is that the id might be identical with another id of another node. Using DISTINCT will cause problem in this case, right?

Comment: Yes. in that case, you should use a property that is unique instead of `id`. If you don't have something that is guaranteed to be unique, you could use the internal ID (via `ID(z)`). A node's internal ID will be unique, but be aware that if the node is deleted its internal ID can be re-assigned to a new node. Or, you can just the nodes themselves (i.e., replace `z.id` with `z`) -- but they will not be simple strings.

Comment: Ok. Great. I will try this first think tomorrow: MATCH (n {gid:'58731'})-[:contains*1..]->(z) RETURN ID(z) as names

Comment: Use this query instead: `MATCH (n {gid:'58731'})-[:contains*1..]->(z) RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT ID(z)) as names`.  The `COLLECT()` will create a collection for you (instead of multiple rows). The `DISTINCT` is there in case the same node appears multiple times in the result set.